# Determine monodromy representation from local system

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, covering-spaces, monodromy, local-systems

Let $X$ be a path-connected manifold nice enough such it's universal covering
space $p:\widetilde{X} \to X$ exists, $k$ a field. Then there exist a wellknown
correspondence

$$
\{\textit{linear}\text{ representations of }\pi_1(x,x)\} \leftrightarrow 
\{\text{local systems of }\textit{vector spaces}\text{ on }X\} 
$$

between $k$ linear finite dimensional representations of a fundamental group
$\pi_1(X,x)$ and local systems of $k$ vector spaces.

The map in one direction is defined as follows:
Take a $k$ linear rep $\rho: \pi_1(X,x) \longrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V) $
where $V$ is a $k$ space and consider the associated $V$-bundle as
quotient space
$\widetilde{X}\times_{\rho} V :=(\widetilde{X}\times V)/\pi_1(X,x) $
where $\pi_1(X,x)$ acts on $\widetilde{X}\times V$  via

$$ g \cdot(x,v) := (g \cdot x, \rho(g)\cdot v ) $$

where $g$ acts at the left via monodromy on the covering space.

Obviously the projection to the first coordinate
$p:\widetilde{X}\times_{\rho} V \to X$ has fiber $V$ and if we endow
$V$ with the discrete topology we obtain a local system $\mathcal{F}_{\rho}$
on $X$ defined by sections

$$\mathcal{F}_{\rho}(U)= \{s:U \to p^{-1}(U) \ \vert p \cdot s =1_U \}  $$

for open $U \subset X$. It's easy to check that if $U $ is contractible,
then $p^{-1}(U)\cong U \times V$ and since $V$ has discrete topology,
$\mathcal{F}_{\rho}(U) \cong V$, so it's a local system.

**Question:** Is there an *explicit* construction known to go in another
direction? To start with an local system $\mathcal{F}$ with fibre $V$ and
construct from it explicitly a representation $\rho_F: \pi_1(X,x) \longrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V) $?

I know that it's rather easy to construct it abstractly:
Let $g=[\gamma] \in \pi_1(X,x)$ be a class of a loop, then since $[0,1]$ is
contractible, all local systems on $[0,1]$ are constant sheaves, therefore we
have a chain of abstract isomorphisms

$$  \gamma^*\mathcal{F}_0 \cong \gamma^*\mathcal{F}([0,1])\cong \gamma^*\mathcal{F}_1 =V.$$

Can this isomorphism of $V$ be written down in explicit terms as an element of
$\operatorname{GL}(V)$ if we pick a basis $e_1,\dotsc, e_n$ of $V \cong k^n$?

**Motivation** of the question: In Geordie Williamson's [An illustrated guide to perverse sheaves](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/geordie/perverse_course/lectures.pdf)
in example 5.11 one considers for $X:= \mathbb{C}^*$ and $k:=\mathbb{C}$ the
covering map $f:\mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}^*: z \mapsto z^m$.
Let $\underline{k}$ be the constant sheaf on $\mathbb{C}^*$ with value
$k=\mathbb{C}$ regarded as 1D vector space.

One considers the pushforward sheaf $f_*\underline{k} $ which has as stalk
at $x=1$ the functions from the $m$-set $f^{-1}(x)$ to $k$, which is isomorphic to $k^m$.
And then it is claimed that $f_*\underline{k} $ is a local system
determined by the action of the monodromy on the $m$-th roots of $1$.

And I was wondering how to check this claim explicitly, even though this sounds
plausible. To come back to the question I posed above it suffices to check that
$f_*\underline{k} $ induces the repr $\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^*,1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \to 
\operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb{C})$ which maps the generator $1$ to
$m$-cycle mapping for a fixed ordered basis $e_1,e_2,\dotsc, e_m$ of $k^m$ the basis vector
$e_i$ to $e_{i+1}$.

Comment: Did you really mean $\operatorname{GL}_m(\mathcal C)$ at the end, and note $\operatorname{GL}_m(\mathbb C)$? \\ TeX note: `\mathrm` is not for "`\rm` in a math-mode environment", but for "math in `\rm`".  For the latter, you want something like `\textrm`, although actually it's just `\text`.  Note $\text{local systems}$ `\text{local systems}` vs. $\mathrm{local systems}$ `\mathrm{local systems}`.  Similarly for `\mathit`, which in your case should have been `\textit`.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: Starting with a local system, can you define the map as follows? Take your fiber $V$ over a basepoint $x \in X$, pull it back via a local isomorphism $p$ to a point $\tilde{x} \in \tilde{X}$ over $x$, apply a deck transformation $g$, and then define the representation to act on $V$ via $\rho(g) = \pi_* \circ g \circ (p_*)^{-1}$. If you have a reasonably explicit description of your covering map I think you can make this pretty explicit. Perhaps you run into a similar problem by trying to explicitly describe the pullback of your local system to a local system on $\tilde{X}$ though

Comment: The word "explicit" is ambiguous. "Algorithmic" is better, but then the input data has to be given in a suitable form. One way to define a flat bundle in a computable form is via a 1-cocycle for a sufficiently good finite open cover. The next issue is the fundamental group: one can describe a cover by its nerve. The 1-skeleton of the nerve will determine the group generators (once a maximal tree is chosen). Given all this, there is a relatively straightforward algorithm for computation of images of generators.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Could you explain in a bit more details how to describe a cover from the nerve data - ie the simplicial model of classifying space - 
of the fundamental group as you suggest?

Comment: Later. But the direction is the opposite one: a cover determines its nerve, a cocycle defined via the cover defines a group homomorphism.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: just to be sure that we are talking about the same construction: by nerve constructed from a cover you mean the Cech nerve (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cover#definitions), right? (sorry, if it's cristal clear, I'm far from beeing an expert on field of simplicial techniques)

Comment: Yes, Chech.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to fill in the details. For simplicity, write $I = [0,1]$ for the interval, and $\exp \colon I \to S^1$ for the function $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$. So let $\gamma = \exp \colon I \to S^1$ be a generator of $\pi_1(S^1,1)$. To get the map $\gamma_* \colon f_*\underline k \to f_*\underline k$, we need to *find* a trivialisation of $\gamma^*f_* \underline k$. Luckily, this is not too hard. First, consider the pullback square
$$\begin{array}{ccc}X & \stackrel p \to & S^1 \\ \!\!\!\!{\small q}\downarrow & & \downarrow{\small f}\!\!\! \\ I & \stackrel\gamma\to & S^1.\!\end{array}$$
Then $X$ is a disjoint union $\coprod_{a \in \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z} I$ of $m$ copies of $I$ that each map isomorphically to $I$ under $q$, and $p \colon X \to S^1$ is given on the $a$-th copy by $x \mapsto \exp((x+a)/m)$. In other words, $X$ is obtained from the top copy of $S^1$ by breaking it up into $m$ pieces by cutting at the roots of unity.

Now we claim that $\gamma^*f_*\underline k$ is naturally isomorphic to $q_*p^*\underline k$. There is always a map
$$\gamma^*f_*\underline k \to \gamma^*f_*p_*p^* \underline k = \gamma^*\gamma_*q_*p^*\underline k \to q_*p^*\underline k$$
coming from the unit $1 \to p_*p^*$ and counit $\gamma^*\gamma_* \to 1$ of the adjunctions $p^* \dashv p_*$ and $\gamma^* \dashv \gamma_*$ respectively. In this case, the map $\gamma^*f_* \underline k \to q_*p^*\underline k$ is an isomorphism, either by checking directly at stalks, or by invoking (an easy case of) the proper base change theorem.

Of course $p^*\underline k$ is just the constant sheaf $\underline k$ (this holds for pullback of any constant sheaf along any continuous map), and $q_*\underline k$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{a \in \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z}\underline k$, giving the required trivialisation. Under this isomorphism, the fibre at $0 \in I$ is $\bigoplus_{a \in \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z} \underline k_{\exp(a/m)}$, whereas the fibre at $1 \in I$ is $\bigoplus_{a \in \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z} \underline k_{\exp((a+1)/m)}$ (where we express everything in terms of the stalks of $\underline k$ in the upper copy of $S^1$). Both of these are isomorphic to $(f_*\underline k)_1$, but in ways that differ by a cyclic shift. $\square$

**Summary.** Don't just compute the isomorphism types of various vector spaces, but remember the isomorphisms. All the data is there, but only once you choose a trivialisation of $\gamma^* \mathscr F$.

**Remark.** There are alternative viewpoints that are also fruitful. For instance, locally trivialising $\mathscr F$ and comparing the trivialisations on the intersections gives a cocycle in $H^1(X,\operatorname{GL}_r(\underline k))$ (cohomology in the constant sheaf of non-abelian groups $\operatorname{GL}_r(\underline k)$). This set also classifies $\operatorname{GL}_r(k)$-torsors over $X$, which is the same thing as $\operatorname{GL}_r(k)$-covering spaces. These are again in correspondence with $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(X,x),\operatorname{GL}_r(k))$. But we have gained a point of view using local trivialisations of $\mathscr F$ on $X$, which is often easier to work with than global trivialisations of $\gamma^* \mathscr F$ on $I$.

Comment: concerning your remark on alternative viewpoint of the monodromy
action associated to local system $\mathcal{F}$ in terms of a
cocycle in $H^1(X,\operatorname{GL}_r(\underline k))$.
do I understand it correctly that you pursue following stategy:
Let $\gamma \subset X$ be a loop in "nice enough" space $X$.

Comment: Let $(U_i)_i^n \subset X$ be a family of open subsets of $X$
with following properties: (1) $\gamma \subset \bigcup_i U_i $
(2) $U_i$ and $U_i \cap U_{i+1}$ non empty & contractible,
while $U_i \cap U_j$ for $\vert i-j \vert >1$ empty, except for 
$i=1, j=n$ (3)$\mathcal{F}$ trivializes over every $U_i$
(4) $U_i \cap \gamma $ contractible (5) $\gamma^{-1}(U_i)=
[k_{i,1}, k_{i,2}] \subset I $ is an interval.

Comment: Then by construction of $U_i$
we have $[k_{i,1}, k_{i,2}] \cap [k_{i+1,1}, k_{i+1,2}]= 
[k_{i+1,1}, k_{i,2}]$ and $[k_{i,1}, k_{i,2}] \cap [k_{j,1}, k_{j,2}]$
for $\vert i-j \vert >1$ empty. Then $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$ trivializes 
over each $[k_{i,1}, k_{i,2}]$. Fix now for each $i$ an explicit isom
$f_j: k^n \cong \gamma^* \mathcal{F}([i_j,i_{j+1}])$ 
(I think here exactly appears the point you emphasised in
 your summary that we need an explicit choice).

Comment: We remember the datum $(g_i)_i^n$ comming from 
isoms $g_i: k^n \cong  \gamma^* \mathcal{F}([k_{i,1}, k_{i,2}]) \cong
\gamma^* \mathcal{F}([k_{i+1,1}, k_{i,2}]) \cong
\mathcal{F}([k_{i+1,1}, k_{i+1,2}]) \cong k^n$
given as composition of $f_j$, can restriction and $ f_{j+1}^{-1}$.

Comment: Then the associated monodromy rep should be given by 
mapping the class $[\gamma]$ to product $g_n \cdot g_{n-1} \cdot ...
\cdot g_1$. By the the way $(g_i)_i^n$ would be the cocyce data
of $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$. Is the argument correct?

Comment: Remark: If what I have wrote in the comments above is correct, then it seems that using this cocycle approach the key to obtain the "right" cocycle which defines the monodrmy map lies in the aspect that we trivialize $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$ in $I$ over a cover which comes from a "cover" of image $\gamma$. Othrwise we could for example triavialize $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$ over single chart cover $I$, but that would not give to as the monodromy image of class $[\gamma]$. It seems that what we are really pursueing is the cocycle of the restriction $\mathcal{F} \vert _{\bigcap U_i}$. But I'm not sure

Comment: I suppose this is the hands-on way to work this out. The more high-brow way to say the same thing is that you consider the espace étalé of the $\operatorname{GL}_r(\underline k)$-torsor and use path lifting. This torsor can be directly obtained from $\mathscr F$ as the sheaf hom $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr F,\underline k^r)$. Path lifting is exactly this thing with the intervals that you mention. (The advantage of this methods over the one in the answer is that you can do it for all paths simultaneously, instead of coming up with a trivialisation of $\gamma^*\mathscr F$ for each path $\gamma$.)

Comment: sidenote: in last sentence I of course meant 
$\mathcal{F} \vert _{\bigcup U_i}$.
But there is another issue I not completely understand. Maybe this is precisely what you mean by using
 $\mathscr Isom(\mathscr F,\underline k^r)$
with $\operatorname{GL}_r(\underline k)$-torsor structure as object that captures
the whole "information" *simultaneously* where
each class of path $\gamma$ going to be mapped, ie 
it knows completely the assoc map $\pi_1(X,x), \to \operatorname{GL}_r(k)$.

Comment: Now going a step back, say we only want to know where the class
of a concrete picked loop $[\gamma]$ going to be mapped by the induced
monodromy map (so we are interested really only in where $[\gamma]$
is mapped, not the whole map), and pose the question which "datum" is already
sufficient to know it? Surely, in terms from above
the restriction of $\mathcal{F}$ to the trivializing family
$(U_i)_i \subset X$ containing $\gamma$ suffice, but the question
is if we can reconstruct to image of $[\gamma]$ by a datum
purely on the side of $I$?

Comment: And here so far I understand your point correctly with the meaning
of the hom sheaf and it's intrinsic nature for keeping track of
choosen isomorphisms, that in contrast the isom class of the local system 
$\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$ on $I$ alone not suffice to determine 
the image of $[\gamma]$ under to monodromy map,
but $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$ **together** with a concrete choice of 
an isomorphism $i: \gamma^* \to \underline k^r$. And this additional data piece is exactly what

Comment: distinguishes the 
$g_n \cdot g_{n-1} \cdot ... \cdot g_1 \in \operatorname{GL}_r(k)$
constructed in comments above from the cocycle $(g_i)_i^n$ comming from
the concrete trivialization of $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$ on $I$ which 
in turn "pulls back" from trivialization $(\bigcup U_i)_i$, which 
looks like a "promising candidate" for the image of 
$[\gamma]$ under monodromy map, in contrast to "wrong image candidate" 
which one might try naively to contruct from $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$
over $I$ itself as trivialization in $I$, which would give 
an identity map, that would be look fishy.

Comment: So this would mean that the reason that the latter would be the "wrong image candidate" for the image of $[\gamma]$ under the monodromy map reflects
the error above to naively assume that the image of $[\gamma]$ is already
determined by the isom class of $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$ alone and ignoring
the neccessarity to specify as additional data a concrete 
isom $i: \gamma^* \mathcal{F} \to \underline k^r$. Is this "the philosophy behind" the ism sheaf which captures the neccessarity here to keep track for concrete

Comment: isomorphism instead of isom classes, which alone -as I tried to understand above - not suffice to reconstruct the monodromy map?

Comment: Typo: p should be $exp(2\pi i/m(x+a))$

Comment: @Mathstudent as I defined $\exp \colon I \to S^1$ to be a generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$, this means I'm taking the convention that $\exp(x) = e^{2\pi i x}$ (or its multiplicative inverse, I suppose). I think this notation is not uncommon; for instance it is the Lie theoretic exponential on $S^1$.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would say that there is no way around the fact that the answer uses the fact that a sheaf on $[0,1]$ is constant.

Does this help? Instead of the pushforward of the constant sheaf $k$ of one-dimensional vector spaces, first think about the pushforward of the constant sheaf $1$ of one-element sets. Its stalk at $x$ is $f^{-1}(x)$. Think about the monodromy. In general, if $f:E\to X$ is any covering space, think about the monodromy of $f_\ast 1$ where $1$ is the constant singleton sheaf.

Here is another piece of advice: since you know what representation $(V,\rho)$ you're supposed to be getting, why not start with an explicit description of a universal covering space of $X=\mathbb C^\ast$ and try to see a bijection between $\tilde X\times_\rho V$ and the union of the stalks of $f_\ast k$?

Comment: Below R. van Dobben de Bruyn's answer I gave in the comments a sketch 
how I would like to try to constuct the monodromy repr
from cycle data of $\gamma^* \mathcal{F}$. 
But if I'm not missing something the same construction
should go through with 
$\mathcal{F}:=f_*1$ since the only difference would be that in your 
example $\mathcal{F}:=f_*1$ would be a set valued local system,
so the $g_i$ would be live in $\text{Aut}(f^{-1}(x)) $, so the 
product $g_n \cdot g_{n-1} \cdot ...\cdot g_1$ still makes sense.

Comment: Is this the kind of approach you suggested to apply to $f_*1$ to extract the monodromy in second paragraph of your answer or did you had there another approach in mind?